# Attribute is not showing on swagger request after moving from Json.Net to System.Text.Json

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, swagger, swagger-ui, system.text.json

I am trying to move from Json.Net to system.Text.Json library in .Net core 3.1. I notice an odd behavior, that swagger doesn't show the attribute that have `[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]` on the request UI.
**system.Text.Json**

The request class :

```
public class AdvancedSearch 
{
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public int? StatusID { get; set; }

        public int? SessionCode { get; set; }

        public int? KeywordVersionID { get; set; }
}
```

Swagger UI :
[image]

**Json.Net**
The request class :

```
public class AdvancedSearch 
    {
            [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
            public int? StatusID { get; set; }
    
            public int? SessionCode { get; set; }
    
            public int? KeywordVersionID { get; set; }
    }
```

Swagger UI :
[image]

newtonsoft works as it supposed to, serialize/deserialize while ignoring null values, but still showing them on swagger UI.

Is there a way to have System.Text.Json do the same ?

Comment: [`JsonIgnoreAttribute.Condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute.condition?view=net-5.0) was introduced in .NET 5.  It's not available in [.NET Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute.condition?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1).  Are you sure you are not using a version of swagger intended for .NET Core 3.1 (which won't know about `JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull`) with .NET 5?  Or mixing up versions in some other way perhaps?

Comment: What are the exact names and versions of the framework and optional nuget(s) you are using?

Comment: "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.4" 
"Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="6.1.4"
"Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="7.0.2"

Comment: Just downgraded to  "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.46.1.4" & "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="5.4.1" .. but problem persists.

Comment: Downgrading won't help, it would be better to use the latest versions as they are more likely to have full .NET 5 support.  But it looks to be a known bug, see [JsonIgnoreCondition is not respected #1899](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1899).